# UIWindow subclass not rotating when UIKeyboard pops up

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have a `UIWindow` subclass called `QueryView` which I present like this:

```
QueryAlertView *queryAlertView = [QueryAlertView  queryAlertViewWithType:queryAlertViewType message:message];
queryAlertView.queryAlertViewDelegate = self;
self.currentAlertView = queryAlertView;
queryAlertView.rootViewController = self;
[queryAlertView makeKeyAndVisible];
[queryAlertView launchKeyboard];

- (void) launchKeyboard
{
    [self.textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

When I launch a `QueryAlertView` in landscape orientation, sometimes it does not rotate to the correct orientation. I'm unable to reproduce this bug and am unsure what is causing it. I was wondering, can anyone see a flaw in my code that could be causing this, or is this an `iOS8` bug?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a bug, attaching a UIView to UIWindow won't know its orientation, only a UIViewController can know.
Attaching anything to UIWindow is an absolute pain.

IMO, a better way to something like https://github.com/TeehanLax/UIViewController-Transitions-Example
This uses iOS 7's UIViewController Animated Transitioning so this code is reusable for any view controller you want to present on top.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at it, though for this particular problem trying to work within the context of what I already have, but I can't find a solution I'll have to think about another method.